# Extract digits with decimal from a vector R

Tags: r, string, extract, stringr

I have the following vector:

```
c("c(`Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared` = 201.760850624131)", "c(df = 17)", 
"1.26686891197831e-33", "Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test", "delta_Z by criteria"
)
```

I desired this output:

```
c("201.760850624131", "17", "1.26686891197831e-33")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: This looks like you've used `paste()` where you shouldn't have.  Rather than trying to extract the info you're interested in via regex, it would be better to go back to the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` with the regex that matches one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) followed by a `.` then one or more digits and e followed by `-` or `+` and any digits

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(na.omit(str_extract(v1, "[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+e[-+]\\d+)?")))
```

-output

```
[1] 2.010000e+02 1.700000e+01 1.266869e-33
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("c(`Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared` = 201.760850624131)", "c(df = 17)", 
"1.26686891197831e-33", "Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test", "delta_Z by criteria"
)
```

Comment: I think `1.26686891197831e-33` should be 0 when coerce it to be numeric

Answer (score 3):

We can try using `str_extract` here for a regex option:

```r
x <- c("c(`Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared` = 201.760850624131)",
       "c(df = 17)", 
       "1.26686891197831e-33",
       "Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test",
       "delta_Z by criteria"
)
output <- as.numeric(na.omit(str_extract(x, "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:e[+-]\\d+)?")))
output

[1] 2.017609e+02 1.700000e+01 1.266869e-33
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\\d+` match an integer component
- `(?:\\.\\d+)?` optional decimal component
- `(?:e[+-]\\d+)?` optional exponent (either positive or negative)

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears to be R code:

```r
x <- c("c(`Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared` = 201.760850624131)", "c(df = 17)", 
"1.26686891197831e-33", "Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test", "delta_Z by criteria")

as.character(sapply(sapply(x[1:3], str2lang, USE.NAMES = F), eval))

#> [1] "201.760850624131"     "17"                   "1.26686891197831e-33"
```